# Translate simple array into key=>value array the fastest way

Tags: php, arrays, preg-split

I want to transfer

```
Array
(
    [0] => name|smith
    [1] => kid|tom
    [2] => wife|emily
)
```

The fastest, smartest way into

```
Array
(
    [name] => smith
    [kid] => tom
    [wife] => emily
)
```

It's not a big deal to use foreach for that. But I would prefer a smart one-liner.

Comment: Just because you could do this in a one-liner, doesn't mean it's better or more readable than a foreach loop

Comment: You can use Regex for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) function:

```
$a = array
(
    0 => 'name|smith',
    1 => 'kid|tom',
    2 => 'wife|emily'
);

$new_arr = array();

array_walk($a, function($v, $k) use(&$new_arr){
    $arr = explode('|', $v);
    $new_arr[$arr[0]] = $arr[1];
});
print_r($new_arr);
```

**output**

```
Array
(
    [name] => smith
    [kid] => tom
    [wife] => emily
)
```

Comment: YEAH! That did it. You are a smart sun of a gun. Thanks very VERY much. I am going to use this - unless someone comes up with a native php function which nobody has seen until now :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are more than one ways to skin a cat.

Using [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) (not in a single line, though):

```
$result = array_reduce(
    $a,
    function (array $carry, $item) {
        list($key, $value) = explode('|', $item);
        $carry[$key] = $value;
        return $carry;
    },
    array()
);
```

And a solution in a single line:

```
array_column(array_map(function($item) { return explode('|', $item); }, $a), 1, 0)
```

Please note that it requires PHP 5.5 (this is the version when the function [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) was introduced).

Comment: A VERY smart way of handling it. Too bad I am using PHP 5.4.

Answer (score 0):

Not a one-liner, but...

```
<?php

$a = array(
    'name|smith',
    'kid|tom',
    'wife|emily',
);

$a2 = array();

foreach($a AS $val) {
    list($key, $value) = explode("|", $val);
    $a2[$key] = $value;
}

print_r($a);
print_r($a2);
```